# Removing an item form foreach loop that is in other foreach and use the same list

Tags: java, list, foreach

I need to remove object from list that is in foreach that is in another foreach to not check objects with the same name (but different other values in that object).

```
for (Foo foo : fooList) {
    // some code
      for (Foo foo2 : fooList){
        if (foo2.getName() == foo.getName()) {
          // some code that stores and manipulates values from foo2
          fooList.remove(foo2);
        }
      }
      //some code that using values from many foos with the same name
    }
```

of course this not working.

I was trying do something with Iterator

```
Iterator<Foo> iterator = fooList.iterator();

while (iterator.hasNext()) {
      Foo foo = iterator.next();
      // some code
      while (iterator.hasNext()){
        Foo foo2 = iterator.next();
        if (foo2.getName() == foo.getName()) {
          // some code that stores and manipulates values from foo2
          iterator.remove();
        }
      }
      //some code that using values from many foos with the same name
    }
```

but this not do the thing either...
using `Iterator<Foo> iterator = Iterables.cycle(fooList).iterator();` was not a good idea too.

I will be grateful for any help!

Comment: Make a copy. You can't remove an item from a list that you're iterating through without problems

Comment: The first code will definitely not work as it will throw a `ConcurrentModificationExeption`. The second code could probably be made to work if you would use separate iterators. Also note that you shouldn't use `==` here. But to be honest, it is not entirely clear to me what you want to achieve. Consider adding an explanation and example.

Comment: If you provide a bigger picture of the problem you may get a better help. What are you really trying to achieve here?

Comment: Why are you iterating the same list twice? With one nested in the other? Can't think of any reason why this would make sense

Comment: I need to remove from list things that have the same names before first loop will go to the first duplicate. But also I need to do some operations on other values stored in this objects

Answer (score 0):

First, @Override `equals()` in class `Foo` to decide what's the attributes that make two objects equals and one of Concurrent implementations of a list like `CopyOnWriteArrayList` to allow you make modification while looping over the list

```
    static class Foo {
        int id;
        String name;

        public Foo(int id, String name) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            Foo other = (Foo) obj;
            return this.name.equals(other.name);
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return id + ", " + name;
        }
    }
```

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Foo> list1 = new CopyOnWriteArrayList<>();
        List<Foo> list2 = new ArrayList<>();

        Foo f1 = new Foo(1, "one");
        Foo f2 = new Foo(2, "two");
        Foo f3 = new Foo(3, "three");
        Foo f4 = new Foo(4, "four");

        list1.add(f1);
        list1.add(f2);
        list1.add(f3);
        list1.add(f4);

        list2.add(f1);

        System.out.println("before remove");
        System.out.println(list1);

        for (Foo f : list1) {
            if (list2.contains(f))
                list1.remove(f);
        }

        System.out.println("after remove");
        System.out.println(list1);
    }
```

, output

```
before remove
[1, one, 2, two, 3, three, 4, four]
after remove
[2, two, 3, three, 4, four
```

Comment: For more details about the concurrent collections: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/collections.html

Answer (score 0):

If you need just to remove duplicates from the `fooList` by specific property, you could try this approach:

```
List<Foo> foosUniqueByName = fooList.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Foo::getName)) // group by name to
                .values().stream()                            // list of lists of foo
                .map(list -> list.get(0))                     // select the first foo
                .collect(Collectors.toList());                // get new list
```